# A grid of boxes with no outer border, but with all inner borders

Tags: css

The effect I'm going for:

[image]

I'm using a foreach loop to display the divs in this container element.  The quick-and-dirty would be to do index % 4 (or whatever the number-of-divs-per-row is) and style accordingly, but I'm looking for a css-only approach if there is one.

One thing I'm playing with now is applying a white border to the container element that has negative margins, to cover up the borders of the outer divs... what other alternatives are there?

EDIT: I'm trying the "White border around container" method but it's not working because I'm floating the divs left (for responsive-ness) - so as soon as the white border of the container element overlaps the black border of the div, the div gets pushed to the next line.

Comment: Will there always be a fixed amount of divs, and will they always be positioned the same way? Or does it need to be dynamic to accommodate changes?

Comment: @BlakeMann - it needs to be dynamic - it's a dynamic number of divs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've got two answers for you to consider... The first one is pure css like you requested, and the second utilizes a small amount of php along with css. Typically, pure css solutions are desirable, but depending on the situation, the second solution could have some benefits as well.

So, first of all, the css. You were definitely on the right track with the outer border covering the borders of the divs. I adapted your approach a little bit though. Rather than putting that border on the parent element, I created an extra child (a span in this case) and positioned it absolutely within the parent, to span the full width and height. I put the border on this, instead of the parent, and since it is absolutely positioned, it doesn't interfere with the positioning of the other elements.

Also, `box-sizing: border-box;` could come in handy if you are having troubles with borders breaking the layout. I utilized that in my examples.

Here's the demonstration for that approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/PGygr/

---

As for the second solution, I used some more advanced selectors to override certain borders on certain boxes. That way, they aren't just hidden.. they're actually not there. For that reason, I would prefer to use this solution over the first, but that's just my opinion.

First, i put a border right and border bottom on all of the divs. This will be correct for all of the divs except for the last of each row, and all of the ones in the bottom row.

To select the last div in each row to cancel out it's right side border, I can do something like this:

```
.container div:nth-child(Xn) {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Where the 'X' would be replaced with the number of divs in each row. If I do this with embedded styles, I can use php to dynamically put that number there.

To select and deactivate the bottom borders for the last row, I can do something like this:

```
.container div:nth-child(X) ~ div {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Again, the 'X' would be placed in with php, and would be equal to the number of divs in each row, multiplied by the number of rows, minus one. So basically, select all of the divs that come after the last div in the second last row.

Here's the fiddle to demonstrate, minus the php aspect of it (I've manually entered the numbers into the css)

http://jsfiddle.net/t7atH/

Whether you decide to stick with the css only approach, or try adding in a little php, I hope this helps you. Best of luck!

**UPDATE:** as an afterthought, there is a third solution that I should probably add in. If you are able to add in row elements wrapping around the divs, you can utilize `:first-child` and `:last-child` to disable your borders.

It's fairly self-explanatory I think, so just take a look at the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/PGygr/3/

Comment: Dude!  So cool!  I'm trying your first suggestion now and running into a problem where the border is being overlapped (as I want), but I can't click on the containing divs: http://jsfiddle.net/PGygr/1/  thoughts?

Comment: Needing to click through certainly makes it trickier.. Simplest solution would be to put `pointer-events: none;` on that span, but browser support is bad, I don't think any versions of IE will accept it. So, if that doesn't work for you, you could always use 4 separate override elements for each side: http://jsfiddle.net/PGygr/2/ ... It's definitely a messy solution, and I wish I had something better for you, but I can't think of anything, without utilizing javascript. My second solution in the answer is still my most favored in this case.

Comment: I'm glad that works for you. I added a third solution as well.. I had skipped over it initially because I didn't know if it would suit your case, but I decided it would be good to post.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very simple solution using css grids - but it only works if there is no empty cell in your grid.

```
.container {
display: grid;
grid-gap: 2px;  /* the length of inner borders */
background-color: black;  /* the color of the inner borders */
}
.cell {
background-color: white;
}
```

The idea is to fill the container with a background color. Each cell will re-ink with its own background color, only leaving the gap visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/mq8Ldpbt/

Answer (score 2):

I needed a solution to the same problem and used Blake's first solution - thanks!

However, I decided to do it slightly differently... rather than add an extra element to the markup I used a CSS pseudo element.

```
.container:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 2px solid #eee;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Avc2v/

Comment: This is a nice solution but it has a pretty big drawback: it forbids interaction with the inner elements. To cover the outer border, the pseudo-element has to be on top of the others. This means that if you have, for example, a link in one of the inner boxes you cannot click it.
EDIT: I just noticed that the same issue has been pointed out in @Blake Mann's answer. A workaround for your approach is setting only `border-bottom` and `border-right`, and then using `.container:before` to cover the outer right border and `.container:after` to cover the bottom one.

Comment: Jsfiddle for my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Avc2v/9/ (There is still an off-by-one error due to the pseudo-elements' `background-color` covering the grid, but it's invisible if boxes have no background color, and it could also be fixed with an ad-hoc `background-image` if it is really needed.)

Comment: To make the content interactive, simply add `pointer-events: none;` to the `.container:before` so user can click through it.

Answer (score 2):

I look at all the solution and I found this one to be the best. Because it is responsive. So I edited a bit that it looks and works much better ...

### How does it work?

What we are doing is adding a pseudo class with empty content with the width of 1px and hight of 1px to the top and to the left of the container div [labeled with ".border-override"].

Note: this solution is quite the same as the one on top of the page, the tiny difference is that the one on top of the page run into bugs when using it for divs with different width and different ordering on screens with different widths. [Thanks for the top page response though, but using PHP and CSS, is like trying to hardcode table! If you know the last row and last column, you are kind of drawing a table, so better use a table than the hassle of divs ...]

[Fiddle](//jsfiddle.net/lostideaslab/cu816n57/)

```
<style>
.border-override {
background: white;
position: relative;
}
.border-override::before {
position:absolute;
height:1px;
width:100%;
top:-1px;
left:0;
background-color: white;
border:1px solid white;
z-index:100;
content: ' ';
}
.border-override::after {
position:absolute;
width:1px;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:-1px;
background-color: white;
border:1px solid white;
z-index:100;
content: ' ';
}
.border-override div {
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
border-top: 1px solid blue;
border-left: 1px solid blue;  
float:left;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
</style>

<div class="border-override">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container > div:nth-child(3n),
.container > div:nth-child(3n-1) {
    border-left: 4px solid white;
}

.container > div:nth-child(n + 4) {
    border-top: 4px solid white
}
```

Explanation :
This is for a 3 x 3 cells grid